# Integro-Differential equation: The arguments should be ordered consistently

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve the following integro-differential equation:

```
γ = 0.024;
eq = μ*D[int[τ, μ, λ], τ] ==int[τ, μ,λ] - 1/(4 π)* Integrate[ int[τ,mup, λ - γ*(1 - (μ*mup + (1 - mup^2)^(1/2)*(1 - μ^2)^(1/2)* Cos[ϕ]))], {mup, -1, +1}, {ϕ, 0, 2 *Pi}];
sol = NDSolve[{eq,int[10, μ, λ] == Exp[-(λ - 200)^2/(2*0.4^2)],int[0, -μ, λ] == 0},int[τ, μ, λ], {τ, 0, 10}, {μ, 0,1}, {λ, 0, 500}]
```

But I obtain the following error:

> NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently

Is it possible to solve that IDE with `NDSolve`?

Comment: Integro-differential equations are not supported by Mma. Only the differential ones. For this reason Mma recognizes that the parameters in the variable int under the integral differ from their order in int in the other positions and informs you.

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch: In the documentation of DSolve[] you can find solution examples for integro-differential equations (MMA v11)

Comment: The error message can be found in Mathematica documentation as `ref/message/NDSolve/conarg`.  Perhaps, Mathematica is confused by the third argument of `int` inside the integral.  In any case, I am not optimistic that Mathematica can solve this integro-differential equation.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Although `DSolve`  can solve integro-differential equations, there is no indication in the documentation that `NDSolve` also can.  Please correct me, if I am mistaken.